# What does "compromise" mean in court context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Mr Seale is in defendant position of the court:

> Kunstler: I'm trying to be clear that I can't muddy Mr. Seale's
> grounds for appeal by appearing to speak as his lawyer.
>
> Judge: I don't ask you to **compromise** Mr. Seale's position, sir.

What does "compromise" mean in court context?
Source: The Trial of the Chicago 7 (2020)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the context the word "compromise" means that *Judge* doesn't want to ask *Kunstler* to make the situation even worse for *Mr. Seale*.

Anyways here is the Oxford dictionary meaning for *compromise*, maybe it can help you:
[Link to Oxford Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/inglese/compromise)

Comment: It's definition C2.